# Custom UI Azure B2C for different websites

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have custom policies for sign up, sign in and reset password. All with custom ui.
I want to have different CSS styles and show different elements for different webs that use the sign up policy. Should I create different sign up policies with different custom UIs to accomplish this?
Also, I want to change the position of the UI fragments embedded by Azure B2C. Is css the only way to change this?

Comment: I think you can create mulitple sign-up/in polices and use different sign-up/in policies for different websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using base b2c policies, then the only way is to create multiple sign-up/in policies. But please keep in mind that there's a **limit to number of policies you can have** in your b2c tenant (currently 100 policies). So if you want to do that also for reset password or any other user journey you will hit that really fast.

So... looking at the tags I can see *Identity Experiance Framework*, in that case you can use sample provided by MS - [active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom-dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom-dynamic) and change your UI based on the additional query parameter that is being sent to policy.

As for moving embedded elements inside your `<div id="api"></div>` CSS is the standard way. But you can look at the [b2clogin.com program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin) that is currently in public preview but it is not recommended to be used for any production use.